# How to change User-Agent in mutt/neomutt?

Tags: mutt

When I send emails from neomutt, the recipient can see the following line in them:

`User-Agent: NeoMutt/20170113 (1.7.2)`

How do I change that line in order to hide that I am using NeoMutt?

I can disable it completely with `use user_agent = no` in *muttrc*, but it would be better to change it to something common instead.

Comment: You can add a custom header with the `my_hdr` command.

Answer (score 4):

Just add the following line to your `.muttrc` file:

```
my_hdr User-Agent: Whatever/1.0
```